# Firebase structure to share data between users on Android

Tags: android, firebase

So I'm using Firebase for my backend on an Android app I'm working on. Currently, my structure looks like this

```
-root

   - users
      - email
         -email
         -firstName
         -lastName

   -(user_email)AppName
      - max
      - workouts
         - workoutName
            - orderNumber
            - some push key id
               - exercise
               - reps
               - sets
```

I'm storing max and workouts under each individual user (user_email + AppName). I want to send workoutName to another user's workouts node. How would I go about this in my rules, and how would I do this programmatically? I also want the user that received the workout to only be able to read it. I was thinking about just copying the workoutName node from a user and inserting it into another user's workouts node.

My rules are currently

```
{ 
"rules": {
".read": "auth != null",
".write": "auth != null"
}
}
```

JSON

```
"testEmail@gmail?comWorkoutTracker" : {
    "workouts" : {
        "benchDay" : {
             "-KyK9ZTc57vvI7QT_UjC" : {
                   "childCount" : "0", 
                   "exercise" : "Bench", 
                   "reps" : "4", 
                   "sets" : "3", 
                   "view" : "Exercise row", 
                   "weight" : "2" 
               }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Are you requiring your users to create an account? If not, change  the rules for the database so that users can read without registering

Comment: Yes, only registered users can read and write

Comment: I don't really understand what sending a workout name to another user means. Instead of showing your data structure, can you show the minimal actual JSON (as text) that shows how you'd like to share the data between users?

Comment: Sending a workout name to another user should in theory send a saved workout, which includes all the exercises and rests created by that user.

There could be multiple children of workouts, and there could be multiple children under each workout name.